# zeppelin user Spark interpreter save DataFrame to Hbase Table

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-zeppelin

I need to built an analytic solution using Zeppelin,read data from Oracle,Hadoop,Hbase,now i need save analytic result to hbase by zeepelin spark interpreter,I write a demo code,This demo is working in Spark develop environment, but it didn't work in zeppelin.

Can somebody help me,Thanks.

```
 %spark
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SQLContext}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job

var sql="select * from analyticresult"

val sqlContext = sqlc

import sqlContext.implicits._
val list = sqlContext.sql(sql)


def getJob(tableName: String): Job = {
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "dn1.hadoop,dn2.hadoop,dn3.hadoop,dn4.hadoop,dn5.hadoop")
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName)

    val job = Job.getInstance(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
    job.setOutputKeyClass(classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable])
    job.setOutputValueClass(classOf[Result])
    job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TableOutputFormat[ImmutableBytesWritable]])
    job
  }

val hbaseRDD = list.mapPartitions( iter => {
      iter.map( it => {
        var rowkey = it.getAs[String](8).getBytes
        var put = new Put(rowkey) //set rowkey
        put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("A"), Bytes.toBytes("CI"), it.getAs[String](3).getBytes)
        put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("A"), Bytes.toBytes("CT"), it.getAs[String](4).getBytes) 
        //Bytes.toBytes(it.getLong(9))

        (new ImmutableBytesWritable, put)

      })
    })

var table = getJob("HWBTEST") 
hbaseRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(table.getConfiguration)
```

The zeppelin console：compile code is normal,but have an IllegalStateException.

```
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@38a0571d
import sqlContext.implicits._
list: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [cardid: string, lineid: string, amount: string, time: string, busline_name: string, vin: string, carno: string, carcolor: string, gpstime: string, systime: string, status: string, alarm: string, lon: string, lat: string, height: string, speed: string, buslineId: string, stype: string, stationSeq: string, stationName: string, stationMark: string, onPersons: string, offPersons: string, buslineName: string, between_time: double, rn: int]
getJob: (tableName: String)org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
hbaseRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put)] = MapPartitionsRDD[276] at mapPartitions at <console>:137
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.ensureState(Job.java:292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.toString(Job.java:457)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.scala$runtime$ScalaRunTime$$inner$1(ScalaRunTime.scala:324)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.stringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:329)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.replStringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:337)
    at .<init>(<console>:10)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor210.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:717)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:928)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:871)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:864)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:94)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:341)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hbaseRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(getJob("HWBTEST").getConfiguration)

Solved the problem